# Put page numbers in front of images in LibreOffice Impress

Tags: libreoffice

In LibreOffice Impress (5.2.7.2), I inserted page numbers in the master slide, positioned almost at the bottom right corner. But in a few slides, there are images occupying the whole space, thus covering the slide number. Is there a way to apply `Arrange -> Bring to Front` to the page number? I did it in the Slide Master view, but it doesn't work. `Send to Back` on the image also doesn't work. Or any workaround? A Google search wasn't successful either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the order of the layers is fixed as follows.

1. Slide Master background
2. Slide background
3. Slide Master objects
4. Slide objects

You tried *Bring to Front* in the 3rd layer, but all that does is rearrange the item relative to other objects in the 3rd layer.  Likewise, you tried *Send to Back* in the 4th layer, but all that does is rearrange the item relative to other objects in the 4th layer.

That leaves two possible solutions.  The first is to move the image to the Slide background (2nd layer in my list above).  This is the answer given to the same question at https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=16025.

The second solution is to move the page numbers to be Slide objects (4th layer in my list).  This approach is recommended at https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7399869.  That question is about PowerPoint, but it's the same issue.

Comment: There are four images on my slide, so the "background image" solution isn't possible. The second solution worked. Thank you!